# Taxonomy of names for template-related syntactic elements in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have been carefully studying templates in C++, and I find it challenging that there appear to be no established set of rigorous terms to clearly identify and distinguish/disambiguate EVERY syntactic element that can appear with the use of templates.

For example, Josuttis and Vandevoorde's often-referenced (and go-to) book on templates, [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](http://amzn.com/0201734842), is an outstanding book - but even that book does not clearly identify the rigorous terms for each syntactic element involving templates.  Instead, the meanings are clear from context.

Consider the following simple example which, I believe, highlights 11 different relevant syntactic components involving templates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template
    <
        typename 

            M1, // <-- (1) "Primary template declaration template parameter
                //          identifier"

        typename M2 // ditto

    > // <-- (2) (entire <...> syntactic element) "Primary template declaration
      //                                           template parameter list"

class Foo
{

    // <-- (3) "Primary class template definition"

};

template
    <
        typename

            T1, // <-- (4) "Template specialization declaration template
                //          parameter identifier"

        typename A1, typename M2 // ditto

    > // <-- (5) (entire <...> syntactic element) "Template specialization
      //                                           declaration template
      //                                           parameter list"

class Foo
    <

        std::vector<T1, A1> &, // <-- (6) "Template specialization
                               //          declaration TEMPLATE PARAMETER
                               //          SPECIALIZATION ARGUMENT"
                               //          (?)

        M2

    > // <-- (7) (entire <> syntactic element) "Template specialization
      //                                        declaration TEMPLATE PARAMETER
      //                                        SPECIALIZATION ARGUMENT LIST"
      //                                        (?)

{

    // <-- (8) "Template specialization class definition"

};

int main()
{
    Foo
        <

            std::vector<int> &, // <-- (9) "Template class instantiation
                                //          template parameter"
                                //          (?) 

            int // diito

        > // <-- (10) (entire <> syntactic element) "Template class
          //                                         instantiation template
          //                                         parameter list"
          //                                         (?)

    f; // <-- (11) "Template class instantiation instance variable name"

}
```

In the code sample, I've indicated 11 different template-related syntactic elements, with my suggested rigorous taxonomic label for each element.

I suspect I'm using correct taxonomic identifiers for most of these elements (but correct me if I'm wrong).

However, syntactic items (6), (7), (9), and (10) are tricky - for example, in the case of (6) and (7), there is the circumstance of template specializations, in which the pair of angle brackets `<>` appears *twice*, so there must be a taxonomic distinction in the identifiers used to indicate the parameters (arguments?) that appear between the angle brackets for these two very different pairs of angle brackets.  Template *instantiations* (9) and (10) involve yet *another* use of angle brackets, so the parameters appearing within those brackets must have their own identifying taxonomic identifier, as well.

Perhaps, in this question, I have used the proper rigorous terminology, but I'd like to know:

1. Is there simpler rigorous terminology than what I've used?
2. Have I used extraneous and/or unnecessary words in my identifying labels?
3. Are there *missing* words in my identifying labels?
4. Am I correct in the identifying labels I have used?

Comment: Did your careful study include the relevant chapter (14) of the C++ standard? That defines the syntax rigorously enough to write a compiler; what do you think is missing from that?

Comment: No.  Good thought.  I will do that.  If someone has the time to summarize and post the relevant syntactic identifiers here, that would answer my question and assist an effort to study the standard.

Comment: The grammar summary is in appendix A.12, but I don't have permission to post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to focus so much on the template parameters, they play the same role everywhere. Some very important terminology, bits of which you didn't mention:

`template<typename T> struct foo;` is a declaration of a primary template.
`template<typename T> struct foo<T*>;` is a declaration of a partial specialization.
`template<> struct foo<int>;` is a declaration of an explicit specialization.

When something like the variable definition `foo<double> f;` is encountered, the instantiation of the appropriate specialization is *sometimes* needed. In particular it's not needed if an explicit specialization is declared. Informally, the process of implicit instantiation is the rewriting of the following:

```
template<typename T> struct foo {
    void bar();
};
template<typename T> void foo<T>::bar() {}
```

to this:

```
template<typename T> struct foo;

template<> struct foo<double> {
    void bar();
};
template<> void foo<double>::bar() {}
```

It is also possible to ask for an instantiation in any given TU, which is called an explicit instantiation:

```
// explicit instantiation declaration, C++11
extern template class foo<double>;
// explicit instantiation definition
template class foo<double>;

// can also instantiate a member of the template more specifically:
template void foo<double>::bar();
```

As the name suggests, explicit instantiation definitions are a way to guarantee that a template (and, if it applies, all of its members) is instantiated. Explicit instantiations declaration are bit of the reverse -- they suppress implicit instantiations, and instead the instantiations produced by a matching explicit instantiation definition will be used. The overall intent of the explicit instantiation feature is to provide ways for programs to 'guide' the compiler to e.g. help with compilation times.

I won't comment as to the quality of implementation of explicit instantiations -- in fact, make note that explicit instantiation declarations a recent addition. I think that you could spend a lot of time with C++ without ever encountering or needing either feature.

Perhaps confusingly, a lot of people will in fact informally use the term 'template instantiation' instead of 'template specialization'. To clarify, the following are all template specializations: `std::deque<int>`, `std::less<T*>` and `std::vector<bool>` (although of course not of the same class template!). Not all uses or mention of a template specialization will trigger or refer to a template instantiations. The fact that it's not necessary to know when or if a template instantiation is triggered is, I think, a convenient feature of templates.

There is in fact something which is called the point of instantiation:

```
// Declare template
template<typename T> struct foo;

// Use template and mention template specialization
// but no instantiation is required here!
typedef foo<int> F;

// Point of instantiation of foo<int>
// an actual definition of foo<int> is needed here
F f;
```

(While I only used class templates here, all of what I describe applies to templates overall, including function templates.)

Comment: Very good answer - thank you.  One tangential (hopefully brief) follow-up, and the only part of your answer that I did not (I think) fully understand: You mentioned a partial specialization near the top of your answer.  Regarding partial specializations: is `template<typename T, typename A> class C<std::vector<T,A> > {}` a partial, or full, specialization of `template<typename T> class C {}` ?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: You only have an explicit specialization if you have `template<>`. As soon as there are template parameters, it's a partial specialization.

Comment: @Xeo Can you confirm that that's true even if none of the template parameters in the specialization correspond to any of the template parameters in the primary template?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: What? The template parameters of a partial specialization have no relation *whatsoever* to those of the primary template. And if you meant something like `template<class A> class C<int>{};`, well, that's simply ill-formed.